# Scanning, OCR and adding the scanned numbers using a Raspberry PI

Tags: hardware

I asked this question on Superuser and was unsuccessful in getting enough attention (even with a bounty on it). So I'm here.
**System setup:**
The intended system will be a **Raspberry PI connected to a scanner**. From the scanner the input would be given to PI and in turn PI shall compute the sum and update a database with the total.
I need to scan hundreds of pages with numbers written on them in the bottom right corner. After the scan - I need a OCR software to recognize the number written at the bottom right corner of each page and sum them in the end.
So far I could scan pages and using OCR in Adobe acrobat, I could identify the hand marked numbers in the pages. Is there a mechanism or any other OCR software that would pass the values to programs like MS Excel.
I tried various OCR programs like Neurograph (opensource) and trial version of other OCR softwares but could not link them directly to scanned files. They have the ability to export the OCR'ed values to Excel but directly do not connect to printer.
Also these softwares run in batches. Is it possible to make the updates a continuous process?
**OR**
Do we have any native OCR application that can be installed in Raspberry Pi?
**The idea is to scan a page (read only the number at the bottom right corner) - OCR that - sum it up - pass the value to Excel**

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

One OCR program that does work on the Pi is Tessereact:

```
sudo apt-get install tesseract-ocr
```

Typical usage is:

```
tesseract page.jpg textfile
```

Comment: Hi, after it becomes a text file will we be able to do addition of a particular number alone?

Comment: Yes, you can parse the resulting textfile.txt as normal.